# Limit test phrase to a few characters

Tags: python, append, limit, suffix

Im having an issue limiting characters not words running different solutions as shown below..any help is appreciated!

```
test_list = ['Running the boy gladly jumped']

test_words = test_list[0].split()

suffix_list = ['ed', 'ly', 'ing']

final_list = []

for word in test_words:
    if suffix_list[0] == word[-len(suffix_list[0]):]:
        final_list.append(word[0:-len(suffix_list[0])])
        
    elif suffix_list[1] == word[-len(suffix_list[1]):]:
        final_list.append(word[0:-len(suffix_list[1])])
        
    elif suffix_list[2] == word[-len(suffix_list[2]):]:
        final_list.append(word[0:-len(suffix_list[2])])
    
    else:
        final_list.append(word)
        
final_list = [' '.join(final_list)]
            
print (final_list)
```

Comment: Which words? The ones in `test_words` or the ones in `final_list`?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to include only the first 8 characters of each word, you can do this with a list comprehension over `final_list` like so:

```
final_list = [word[:min(len(word), 8)] for word in final_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Removes suffixes and limits each result word to `limit` characters

```
limit = 8
test_list = ['Running the boy gladly jumped continuously']
test_words = test_list[0].split()
suffix_list = ['ed', 'ly', 'ing']
final_list = []

for word in test_words:
    for suffix in suffix_list:
        if word.endswith(suffix):
            final_list.append(word[:-len(suffix)][:limit])
            break
    else:
        final_list.append(word[:limit])

print(' '.join(final_list))
```

Prints:

```
Runn the boy glad jump continuo
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use splicing to get the first 8 words

```py
final_list = [' '.join(final_list)][:8]
```